# Electron app - Invoke loadURL function with another html page after some time interval

Tags: electron

can `loadURL` of an electron app be invoked again after some time interval.Can we use Interval or timeout functions in entry main.js. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can invoke the loadURL method again after displaying a page in your main.js.

But make sure you invoke it on the same window.For example,

```
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
setTimeout(function() {
     mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/second.html`)
}, 3000);
```